# Test parse errors in intern do not include the line that describes the error

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, intern

tl;dr When there is an error with a test written in intern I don't seem to get error messages that describe on which line the error occurred. I've found a workaround but its not really the ideal solution as it involves messing with code in dependent projects. Does any one have a better way / am I just doing it wrong? Thanks!

Details : 
I've seen several times that when there is an issue with parsing a test written in intern (for example failing to close brackets, quotes etc.) that the actual line where the error occurred is not reported, and there is only an error like this (I've subbed in  for the actual path as its a work project, but you get the gist):

`SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Function.vm.runInThisContext (<myproject>/node_modules/intern/node_modules/istanbul/lib/hook.js:163:16)
    at <myproject>/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:745:8
    at fs.js:266:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)`

I poked around a little and discovered that there's an undocumented(? - its not in [here](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinthiscontext_code_filename)) parameter for vm.runInThisContext, which if enabled actually provides details of the original error ([here](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/3502) and [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/3570))  - there's some discussion about how this will play out but if I switch dojo.js and hook.js in istanbul (if its running) to use this parameter, I get error messages like this :

`<myproject>/test/publisherConfigSpec.js:16
                    errorCb cat = dfd.rejectOnError(function(error) {
                                  ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Function.vm.runInThisContext (<myproject>/node_modules/intern/node_modules/istanbul/lib/hook.js:163:16)
    at <myproject>/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:745:8
    at fs.js:266:14
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)`

which is the output I want (or at least massively improves my chances of finding and fixing the error) but its not ideal to be messing about with the node dependencies, and it seems to me that it may be too much in flux for a pull request (see [most recent update to the API](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/eef552774e1c78b113e1b543cb9463cd64ecd5ed)) Is there an alternative way of getting useful output when there's an error parsing the test code input?

Thanks for any advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output that Node.js provides for SyntaxError is obviously not great, but we probably won’t use undocumented features (they’re undocumented for a reason!) in any official release of Intern to make it work differently. Non-syntax errors (runtime errors) will be caught and reported competently by Intern to whatever reporters you are using.

In this case, I’d advise you to use an editor that includes support for syntax checking: Komodo Edit/IDE, WebStorm, SublimeText, Eclipse, vim… if you get to the point where you are trying to run syntactically invalid code, your code editor is failing you by not telling you soon enough that you’ve made a mistake.

Comment: Heh fair point, I do use sublime/IntelliJ but I just thought it surprising that the output doesn't help you find the error.  I wouldn't expect you to use the (mildly terrifying) hack either, I was just wondering if there was another way, but you're right, using the IDE works fine. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Oh and I guess in a real project I would also have it hooked up with jshint via grunt so I'd not even get that far from the command line - it was really only trying it out.